# how to write unit test for catching the exception that exception throw in asynchronous block (observable or promise) in a function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6

I want to write unit test for this function getData().

```
getData(){
  this.service.getvalues().subscribe(
        results => {
        },
        err => {
            throw err;
        }
    );
}
```

I tried this

```
it('', async(() => {
      serviceSpy.getvalues.and.returnValue(throwError({}));
      try {
        component.getData({});
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }));
```

This getData function not returning anything.
I put asnyc() in it block to make sure The test will automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone are done.

my problem is I am not able to catch that error 
Because that exception is throwing in asynchronous block

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error throws an error, no matter where it's done.

It's been a while since I used it, but the syntax for this kind of test would be

```
it('', () => {
  serviceSpy.getvalues.and.returnValue(throwError({}));
  expect(() => component.getData({})).toThrow(/* some params */);
});
```

Not sure why you use an async too, so I just removed it.